# Is there a way to make a page do different things based on which id is mentioned in the url?

Tags: php, html

How can I make a page do two different things based on which element's id is mentioned in the URL? For example, if the URL was website.com/page#id1 the page would do one thing, and if it was website.com/page#id2, it would do another?

Comment: Do you want to do this server side or client side?

Comment: either would be fine, but preferably client side I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both server-side and client-side, the answer is yes.

Server-side, your URL would need to be structured differently than you have, for example:

```
http://website.com/page?id=1
```

...or with RESTful routing

```
http://website.com/page/1
```

The latter can be accomplished with something like Apache's `mod_rewrite`.

To access the `id` value within your PHP code, you would `$_GET['id']`, and process it appropriately.

Client-side, you would need to do this using JavaScript using `location.hash` or `location.href`. GitHub does this to great effect with navigable hashing.

Answer (score 0):

Hash part of the URL is not being passed to the server, you will need to employ eg. JavaScript to do that.

In JavaScript "hash" part of the URL is available like that:

```
var hash_part = window.location.hash;
```

and after getting it, you can for example:

- pass it to the server by AJAX call,
- redirect the page that will pass hash to the server, eg. like that:

  ```
  window.location = '/check_hash.php?hash=' + hash_part.split('#')[1]
  ```
- or do something without the need to call the server:

  ```
  alert('My hash is "' + hash_part + '", no need to call the server!');
  ```

Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make use of PHP you can deliver parameters in the URL such as:

```
website.com/page.php?do=something
```

or

```
website.com/page.php?do=somethingelse
```

So you should use a question mark to pass parameters to PHP rather than using the hashtag as you used in your question.

In your PHP code you can then fetch this parameter and do something based on its value:

```
<?php

$param = $_GET['do'];

if ($param == "something") {
   //Do something...
}
else if ($param == "somethingelse") {
   //Do something else...
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Server-side: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php
Client-side you have to use `location.hash` or `location.href` to determine what `id` has been sent to your page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change something on page load depending on a url param you can read it like this

```
if($_GET["id"] == "test"){
  do your stuff
}
```

example here http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0):

If client side then you will need to use javascript. For example

```
<script>
  if (location.hash == 'id1') {
      alert('page1!');
  }
  else if (location.hash == 'id2') {
      alert('page2!');
  }
</script>
```